# Alsa - dmix, softvol config?

Tags: alsa, alsamixer

I want to acheive the following:

A USB DAC is connected to a linux box. So far no issue...

```
card 1: Device [USB Audio Device], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

now my target is to have multiple apps playing back using alsa's dmix module, and those virtual channels should be independent controllable using alsamixer (is this even possible??) - is it possible to map dmix channels to applications? so I could for example have mpd playing always to 2.1 and another app to 2.2?

Comment: No, `dmix` channels don't show up as ALSA plugins, you can't put a softvol plugin in front, and they don't have mixer controls on their own. Would using Pulseaudio be an option? It can do what you want right out of the box.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "channel"? Should mpd play to the left speaker, and the other app to the right one? Or do you want to mix everything together?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question… but here's an answer. Tested with some USB headphones I had to use on a trip, since I left my good ones at home.

My actual config uses an equalization plugin as well, which has been omitted.

Debian Sid was used, without pulseaudio. You just need to have multiple softvol sinks with the same final dmix output as slave, as I understand it.

Define a few of these, where all of them use the same dmix slave at the bottom but each have unique names (maybe `pcm.generic_softvol0`,`pcm.generic_softvol1` and such). Give them different `control` names, too (maybe `soft0`, `soft1` or something).

My USB output just identifies itself with the name "Device" rather than something meaningful. So that's what you're seeing below.

```
# generic headset softvol
pcm.generic_softvol {
  type plug;
  slave.pcm {
    type softvol;
    slave {
      pcm "dmix:CARD=Device,DEV=0";
    }
    control {
      name "soft"
      card "Device"
    }
  }
}
```

with this, you should be able to set an environment variable prior to starting a program to change where it outputs sound to. With this, if you define additional softvol's like the one above, you could tell a specific program to use it for playback (`ALSA_PCM=generic_softvol0 program_name` for instance; if not provided it will use the one defined as `default` instead).

```
pcm.!default {
  type asym
  playback.pcm {
    @func getenv
    vars [ ALSA_PCM ]
    default "generic_softvol" # don't prefix with 'plug:' because generic_softvol is already a plug-type as we've defined it.
  }
  # Put your preferred capture device here for the default.
  capture.pcm {
    @func getenv
    vars [ ALSA_CAPTURE_PCM ]
    default "dsnoop:CARD=Loopback,DEV=1"
  }
}
```